# django login form and form validation with ajax in bootstrap modal

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

i'm new to ajax and i want the user to be able to login with this login form and if the password is incorrect it tells him that signin is invalid without the page being refreshed,the form is contained in a bootstrap modal after checking some answers and some tutorials here is what i tried:

i have a normal login form in my forms.py

**in my views.py**

```
signin_form = SigninForm()
user = request.user
if request.method == "POST":
    if 'signin_form' in request.POST:
        signin_form = SigninForm(request.POST)
        if signin_form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            data['email'] = email
            data['password'] = password
            data['stat'] = "ok"
            return JsonResponse(data)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
            elif user is None:
                messages.error(request, 'ُEmail or password is incorrect')
        else:
            data['stat'] = "error"
```

**the form in the template**

```
  <form action="" method="POST" id="form-signin">
                            {% csrf_token %}

                                    {{signin_form.email}}
                              
                                    {{signin_form.password}}

                            <button class="btn btn-success" id="signin-btn" type="submit" name="signin_form">Sign in</button>

                            {% for message in messages %}

                            <div class="alert alert-danger "> {{ message }}</div>

                            {% endfor %}

                        </form>
```

**in my js file**

```
    $(function () {
    
      $("#signin-btn").click(function () {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              data: $("#form-signin").serialize(),
              success: function (data, status) {
                  if (data['stat'] == "ok") {
                      $('#joinus').modal('hide');
                  }
                  else {
                      $('#joinus').html(data);
                      $('#joinus').modal('show');
                  }
              }
          });
```

with all this code when i click submit a blank page appears that has the json response only  here is an example of what appears:

{"email": "myemail@gmail.com", "password": "mypassword", "stat": "ok"}

if all what i did was wrong please show the method of doing i've looked up to many question but none of them got me to the point

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much based on the code you given but I do know why you get that JSON response. The problem is that you return the Jsonresponse too soon in the code.

```
if signin_form.is_valid():
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        data['email'] = email
        data['password'] = password
        data['stat'] = "ok"
        return JsonResponse(data) --> return before excuting the rest of the code
        if user:
            login(request, user)
        elif user is None:
            messages.error(request, 'ُEmail or password is incorrect')
```

Any coding language I know will not execute code after return statement is invoked. Why is doing it in a blank page? My guess is that you load a blank window in ajax success. what you can do in the success part is to make an if else statment and [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) the invalid attribute in Bootstrap on which input field is giving an error.

```
success: function (data) {
              if (data['stat'] == "ok") {
                //redirect to the login page
              }
              else {
                  //make a if else to show which field is giving error
                  if (data['error'] = 'username){
                   $('#{{signin_form.email.auto_id}}').prop();
                  }
                  //continue the code here....
              }
          }
```

Hope this satisfy your question.

Comment: i'm new so didn't know how to use this prop() can you guide me to the full method?

Comment: you can google it for the guide, like this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758036/how-to-manually-invalidate-fields-after-ajax-call-with-jquery-validate)